# How to deserialilze/serialize "mixed" data structures (in C#)

Tags: c#, json, rest, .net-core

Surprisingly lot APIs have "mixed" data structures (I haven't found a better term for that so far).

I mean something like the API returns an array of objects like:

```
[
  { "x": 10, "y": 20 },
  { "x": 5, "y": 20 },
  "ZERO",
  { "x": 20, "y": 20}
]
```

In some languages it seems pretty regular to mix complex types and enums (?) as placeholder for predefined values. At least a rust developer once told me that he has no problems to handle something like that.

But how can this be handled in C# with e.g. Newtonsoft.Json or Json.NET?

---

Update: fixed the missing quotes around x and y

Comment: Welcome to the wild west of unstructured JSON and inconsistent web requests. The reason is simple, JavaScript and lazy / gung-ho FulLStAcK dEvElOpErS... Anyway, in some cases you will need to write converters for Text.Json or similar, in other cases you are going to have to parse the Json iteratively depending on how munted it is

Comment: I had this problem as well, I resorted to using a `JsonElement`, and then creating a function similar to `JsonDeserialize` it myself taking `JsonElement` as parameter to the function.

Comment: Any opinion how the name that structure in a discussion? So: the term or wording ....

Comment: from json standard's point of view, it is totally valid json. right?

Comment: @LeiYang yes, from the JSON point of view this is valid

Comment: so the term mix or not depends on business requirement, and protocal between client and server.

Comment: @LeiYang Hm, hard to tell if it is just my personal taste but I would not say it is only business requirement. Though it is valid JSON even in JSON those are two different types and therefor the array is "mixed" (imo)

Comment: Seems like there's no builtin way to handle union types. For example [omnisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol) handles [such types](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-17/#serverCapabilities) with custom converters

Comment: 1) That's not well-formed JSON, the property names `x` and `y` need to be quoted: `{"x":10, "y":20}`.  Is that a typo in the question or are the property names really missing quotes?  2) Is the string `"ZERO"` intended to represent the **zero point**?  Or can there be arbitrary strings and other unstructured data in the array?

Comment: @dbc well. A great view for the detail. Though the missing quotes are a typo made by me. This is just a sample that came to my mind. The "ZERO" can be any named representation for predefined values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse it manually like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "[ { x: 10, y: 20 }, { x: 5, y: 20 },'ZERO',{ x: 20, y: 20}]";

    var dynObjects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(str);

    List<C> concretes = new List<C>();
    foreach(var d in dynObjects)
    {
        if(d is string)
        {
            concretes.Add(new C() { Zero = d });
        }
        else
        {
            concretes.Add(new C() { X = d.x, Y = d.y });
        }
    }
}


class C 
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    public string Zero { get; set; }
}
```